# What does MAX apply to on the Memory Cards in "Autumn Harvest: A Tea Dragon Society Card Game"?

Tags: the-tea-dragon-society-card-games

In Autumn Harvest: A Tea Dragon Society Card Game, some memory cards have score wording on them that are unclear to me.

For example, the Winter Memory Card *Crisp Evening* has a score of "4+?" and the card text says

> ?=1 point for each token you have at game end. MAX 12.

I am unclear about if the MAX applies to the **total** card score (the whole bottom of the card that says "4+?") or **only** the "?" that is part of the score equation.

[image: Image of the "Crisp Evening" card from "Autumn Harvest: A Tea Dragon Society Card Game"]

In the example above, if the maximum refers to the card's total score then it would only count up to 8 tokens and would get up to 12 points for this card.

The other way to read it is that the maximum refers to the "?" alone, so you can count up to 12 tokens and would get up to 16 points for this card.

There are some card instances where both the score and "?" are the same so the maximum applies to both, but in this instance because of the "4+?", the score and "?" are not the same and it is unclear which the maximum applies to.

Clarification on this would be very helpful, as there is nothing about this in the [Autumn Harvest rule book](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54148cdae4b05a3412bfa19b/t/5fb40e66b45d862c6ce070e9/1605635689163/Autumn+Harvest+Rulebook.pdf).

Comment: In the absence of official errata, play it as written. Determine the value of ? with the formula given `? = 1 per each, with a max of 12.` And then add that to four to get the score.

Comment: Oh, that's why there were those changes! I didn't realize it was difficult for screen readers and accessibility purposes, I thought it was just user preference. I can roll back to the changes that were made. Thanks for letting me know. I will go update my other questions then as well. :)

Answer (score -1):

MAX is intended to be the maximum amount of points that may be scored with the card.

Comment: Welcome to [boardgames.se]! This answer would be better if you have some kind of reference to back this up.

Comment: ... especially since that answer conflicts with card text. Card text clearly shows the Max being applied to the computation of "?"and the score then being 4 + ?. Errata would be required to change that.